# What is meaning of the black circled function on this multimeter ? How is it used?

Tags: multimeter

[image]

What is the marked (circled in black in multimeter picture) function? It looks like a square wave.

Comment: What does the manual say about it?

Comment: @Justme I have no manual. Also saw some videos. They are explaining all excepting this one

Comment: **SAFETY ADVICE**: **stay away** from this multimeter except for low voltage AND low power circuits. Most probably it has zero (0) safety circuits built-in. Even if it *can* measure 100+ volts, don't even dare use those ranges on anything powerful (like mains-powered things). It could literally explode in your face during a transient event. I wouldn't even use it to test low-voltage high-power circuits, e.g. measuring a 12V car battery, because if you make a connection mistake (e.g. I range instead of V range) the glass fuse inside may not be able to stop the fault current safely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the manual I found online it outputs a square or sine wave depending on the model. But this option isn't available on the DT830D.

Manual can be found at https://www.manualslib.com/manual/848426/Histest-Dt830-Series.html#manual